# gulp-watch runs all tasks if it watches html files

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

There is a task 'serve' with watch functions as shown below:

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
  gulp.watch(['source/scripts/*.js'], ['concatjs', reload]);
  gulp.watch(['source/styles/*.css'], ['concatcss', reload]);
  gulp.watch(['app/static/*.html'], [reload]);
});
```

When I update js or css files gulp executes only *concatjs* or *concatcss* tasks correspondingly. But if to update the html file gulp executes all tasks even the tasks that wasn't registered to the watch function and it throws an error:

```
[18:26:31] Starting 'lesstocss'...                                                                                                          
[18:26:31] Starting 'concatjs'...                                                                                                           
[18:26:31] Starting 'concatcss'...                                                                                                          
[18:26:31] Starting 'serve'...                                                                                                              
[error] You tried to start Browsersync twice! To create multiple instances, use browserSync.create().init()                                 
[18:26:31] Finished 'serve' after 6.1 ms                                                                                                    
[18:26:31] Finished 'lesstocss' after 38 ms                                                                                                 
[18:26:31] Finished 'concatjs' after 47 ms                                                                                                  
[18:26:31] Finished 'concatcss' after 41 ms
```

Maybe gulp works with the html files in another way? All code I use:

```
var gulp            = require('gulp');
var concat          = require('gulp-concat');
var browserSync     = require('browser-sync');
var reload          = browserSync.reload;
var less            = require('gulp-less');
var sourcemaps      = require('gulp-sourcemaps');


gulp.task('lesstocss', function () {
  return gulp.src('source/styles/*.less')
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(less())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('source/styles/'));
});

gulp.task('concatjs', function() {
  return gulp.src(['source/scripts/mls.js', 'source/scripts/main.js'])
    .pipe(concat('result.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/static/scripts/'));
});

gulp.task('concatcss', function() {
  return gulp.src(['source/styles/mls.css', 'source/styles/main.css'])
    .pipe(concat('result.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/static/styles/'));
})

gulp.task('serve', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: "localhost:3000",
    browser: "google chrome",
    notify: false,
    open: 'local'
  });

  gulp.watch(['source/scripts/*.js'], ['concatjs', reload]);
  gulp.watch(['source/styles/*.css'], ['concatcss', reload]);
  gulp.watch(['app/static/*.html'], [reload]);
});
```

Comment: I take it that log is what you see immediately after saving a change one of the `'app/static/*.html'` files? Does `reload` work when you save a change `'source/scripts/*.js'` or `'source/styles/*.css'`? What is your `reload`, and how is your `browserSync.init()` set up?

Comment: @henry yes, I've got this error log after `'app/static/*.html'` was changed. `reload` works with all of that files (js, css, html). Code was added to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var changedInPlace = require("gulp-changed-in-place");
var browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();
var sass = require("gulp-sass");
var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer");
var cleanCSS = require("gulp-clean-css");
// var sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
// var runSequence = require("run-sequence");


// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task("browsersync", ["sass"], function() {

  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./",
      index: "home.html"
    },
    ghostMode: false
  });


  gulp.watch("./scss/*.scss", ["sass"]);
  gulp.watch("./*.html").on("change", browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch("./js/*.js").on("change", browserSync.reload);
});

  // Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task("sass", function() {
    return gulp.src("./scss/*.scss")
    .pipe(changedInPlace())
    .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./css"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

At this point I thought it would be instructive to show my working gulpfile.js.  It uses sass but you can swap that.  Note it uses the preferred

```
var browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();
```

and avoids the unusual and possibly problematic arrays you have in your watch statements.  But if you really have 2 'serve' tasks defined that is probably your problem (see my comment below)

Comment: Only one `serve` task here. I made it short at first post then added the full version.

Comment: `gulp.watch('app/static/*.html').on("change", reload);` I've changed to this. Works fine, thank you.

Comment: @Maxa  If the problem is solved, I wouldn't mind an answer check if you feel that is appropriate.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the following line is valid syntax:

```
gulp.watch(['app/static/*.html'], [reload]);
```

gulp.watch(glob[, opts], tasks)  :  when used this way - as you are doing - tasks is an array of STRINGS which themselves are created by gulp.task(). See the docs

```
Names of task(s) to run when a file changes, added with gulp.task()
```

from https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob--opts-tasks-or-gulpwatchglob--opts-cb

We definitely need to see reload and the rest of your gulpfile.js

Here is sample code which works with browserSync reload for example:

```
 gulp.watch("./scss/*.scss", ["scss-watch"]);
 gulp.watch("./*.html").on("change", browserSync.reload);
      // gulp.watch("./css/*.css").on("change", browserSync.reload);
 gulp.watch("./js/*.js").on("change", browserSync.reload);
```

Comment: I was surprised by `[reload]` as well, but it actually works for the weirdest reason: the tasks in that array are started by [`apply()`ing](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/bfb8522/index.js#L36) them to [`orchestrator.start()`](https://github.com/robrich/orchestrator#orchestratorstarttasks-cb), which as its last argument takes a callback function that is invoked when the tasks have finished executing. So as long as only the last element in your task array is a function, it works. Probably wasn't intended to be used that way however ...

Comment: In the gulp documentation I see two forms of gulp.watch: gulp.watch(glob[, opts], tasks)   and   gulp.watch(glob[, opts, cb])   so you can use a callback function of course but I wouldn't think wrapped in an array and their example doesn't have it so wrapped.  But your explanation looks good.  But I would like to see the OP change it and see what happens - and provide the complete gulfile.js.

Comment: @Mark Code was added to the post. `reload` is the method of browserSync and it reloads the browser after each change. `reload` works  fine here.

Comment: Do you have two 'serve' tasks defined : one to init browserSync and one to do the watching.  Your first code snippet is named 'serve' and within the last longer code snippet you have another 'serve'.  ?